# How can we download large data in excel in .net core

Tags: .net, excel

I have a block of code which fetch the data from the db and transfer it to excel. After that the excelsheet is downloaded. It is working fine when there small amount of data but with large set of data it is causing a lot of time.

I expect the processing to work like in the db where the data are fetched gradually

Comment: Why not paginatie the data by chunk

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user123456 pagination while fetching the data from DB or after that could you please give more context on that?